# Requirement to generate PDF and Word document on click of a button

Tags: visualforce, aura, postmessage

I am getting the data (JSON array) from a service and need to show the data in an Aura component. When the user clicks on a download button in Aura, a popup appears to show the PDF and Word download buttons. I am referring to the post message to pass the JSON data from Aura to VF. But how to get the event.data into a variable that I can use to generate PDF or Word?

I was referred to this [link](https://medium.com/@ToAnshulVerma/salesforce-lightning-generate-pdf-from-lightning-components-with-in-memory-data-cd5dffe0fe25), but I don't want to load the entire component - except for the buttons. Therefore I am trying to use the post message. Is there any way to send data from Aura to VF page to generate PDF or Word documents?
TIA.

```visualforce
<apex:page>

    <script>
        var lexOrigin = "https://yourdomain-dev-ed.lightning.force.com";
        window.addEventListener("message", function(event) {
            if (event.origin !== lexOrigin) {
                // Not the expected origin: reject message!
                return;
            }
            // Handle message
            console.log(event.data);  -->store this in to a variable that I can iterate and apply styles to render.
         }, false);
    </script>
</apex:page>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am able to achieve this as explained below.

sample component:

```
<aura:component 
implements="flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes,flexipage:availableForRecordHome,force:hasRecordId,
force:lightningQuickAction" access="global" >

<aura:attribute name="message" type="String"/>
<aura:attribute name="vfHost" type="String" default="YourVfPage-dev-ed--c.visualforce.com"/>

<!-- Input field for message "data" -->
<lightning:input type="text" label="Message:" value="{!v.message}"/>
<lightning:button label="Send to VF" onclick="{!c.sendToVF}"/>

<!-- The Visualforce page to send data to -->
<iframe aura:id="vfFrame" src="{!'https://'+v.vfHost+'/apex/LcToVfPage'}"/>

</aura:component>
```

VF Page:

```
   <apex:page controller="ShareDataWithVF_controller" 
   lightningStylesheets="true">
<apex:form >
<input type="hidden" id="myInput" value=""/>

<apex:inputhidden id="hidData" value="{!PDFData}"/>
    <apex:commandButton value="generatePDF" id="theButton1" action=" 
    {!downloadPDF}"/>
<apex:commandButton value="generateword" id="theButton2" action=" 
    {!downloadword}"/>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<p id="demo"></p>


<script>
var lexOrigin = "https://YourLightningDomain-dev-ed.lightning.force.com";
window.addEventListener("message", function(event) {
    if (event.origin !== lexOrigin) {
        // Not the expected origin: reject message!
        return;
    }
    // Handle message
    console.log(event.data);
    var datafromLC = event.data;
    console.log('value of datafromLC '  + datafromLC); 
    document.getElementById("myInput").value= datafromLC;
    document.getElementById('{!$Component.hidData}').value= datafromLC;
    console.log('value of hidData '  + 
  document.getElementById('{!$Component.hidData}').value);
   }, false);

    function myFunction() {
   var x = document.getElementById("myInput").value;
   document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = x;
   }
</script>
</apex:form>
    
</apex:page>
```

PDFGenerator VFPage:

```
 <apex:page controller="ShareDataWithVF_controller" renderAs="pdf"> 
{!PDFData}
 </apex:page>
```

WordGenerator VFPage:

```
  <apex:page controller="ShareDataWithVF_controller" 
  contentType="application/vnd.msword">    
{!PDFData}
  </apex:page>
```

Controller:

```
 public class ShareDataWithVF_controller {
 public String PDFData {get; set;}    

public ShareDataWithVF_controller(){
    PDFData = '';        
}

public PageReference downloadPDF(){
    System.PageReference pageRef = new 
System.PageReference('/apex/PDFGenerator');

    //ensure pdf downloads and is assigned with defined name
    pageRef.getHeaders().put('content-disposition', 'attachment; 
   filename=TestPDF.pdf');
 
    return pageRef;
}
public PageReference downloadword(){
    System.PageReference pageRef = new 
    System.PageReference('/apex/WordGenerator');

    //ensure pdf downloads and is assigned with defined name
    pageRef.getHeaders().put('content-disposition', 'attachment; 
   filename=TestWord.doc');
 
    return pageRef;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

below is the way to send the data from the Lightning component to the visualforce page by using Custom Event.

**Step 1** :- Create a Custom Event, this event used to send the data to visualforce page

- SendDataToVFPage.evt

```html
<!-- this event used in SendDataToVFPageComponent -->
<aura:event type="APPLICATION">
    <aura:attribute name="currentRecId" type="String"/>
    <aura:attribute name="CurrentRecDetails" type="Object" />
</aura:event>
```

**Step 2** : Create Lightning Component and register the custom event in Lighting Component

```html
<aura:component>
    <aura:attribute name="strParentId" type="String"/>
    <aura:attribute name="recordFields" type="Object"/>

    <!--This event used to send the data from Lightning component to vf page-->
    <aura:registerEvent name="vfEvent" type="c:SendDataToVFPage"/>

    <aura:if isTrue="{!not(empty(v.strParentId))}">
        <force:recordData aura:id="currentRecord" layoutType="FULL" recordId="{!v.strParentId}" targetFields="{!v.recordFields}"/>
        <h3><b>Showing data from Lightning Component</b></h3><br/>
        <div>
            <lightning:card iconName="standard:account" title="{!v.recordFields.Name}">
                <div class="slds-p-horizontal--small">
                    <p class="slds-text-heading--medium"><lightning:formattedText title="Type" value="{!v.recordFields.Type}"/></p>
                    <p class="slds-truncate">
                        <lightning:formattedText title="Industry" value="{!v.recordFileds.Industry}"/></p>
                    <p class="slds-truncate"><lightning:formattedPhone title="Phone" value="{!v.recordFields.Phone}"/></p>
                </div>
            </lightning:card>
        </div><br/>
        <div style="text-align: center">
            <lightning:button variant="brand" label="Send Data VF Page" onclick="{!c.sendDataVFPage}" />
        </div>
    </aura:if>
</aura:component>
```

when you click the 'sendDataVFPage' button in the Component custom event will fire and it sets the data to the event parameters.

- SendDataToVFPageController.js:-

```js
({
    sendDataVFPage : function(component, event, helper) {
        console.log('current rec details ===> '+JSON.stringify(component.get('v.recordFields')));
        console.log('Parent Id  ===> '+component.get('v.strParentId'));
        if(component.get('v.strParentId')) {
            var myEvent = $A.get("e.c:SendDataToVFPage");
            myEvent.setParams({
                currentRecId: component.get('v.strParentId'),
                CurrentRecDetails: component.get('v.recordFields')
            });
            myEvent.fire();
        }
    }
})
```

**Steps 3** :- Create Lightning out App to call the lighting component from the visualforce page.
add your component in lightning out App.

- DemoLightingOutApp.app

```html
<aura:application extends="ltng:outApp" access="GLOBAL">
    <aura:dependency resource="c:SendDataToVFPage"/>
</aura:application>
```

**Step 4** :- Create Visualforce page and include  <apex:includeLightning /> in page.

- LightingOutPageDemo.page

```html
<apex:page standardController="Account">
    <apex:pageMessages />
    <apex:includeLightning />
    <div id="vfDemo" />

    <apex:pageBlock title="Showing data from visualforce page">
        <apex:pageBlockSection>
            <apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
                <apex:outputLabel value="Account Name" />
                <apex:outputText styleClass="accName" />
            </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
            <apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
                <apex:outputLabel value="Account Industry" />
                <apex:outputText styleClass="accIndustry" />
            </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
            <apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
                <apex:outputLabel value="Account Phone" />
                <apex:outputText styleClass="accPhone" />
            </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
        </apex:pageBlockSection>
    </apex:pageBlock> <br/><br/>

    <script>
        // Calling Lightning component from vf page
        $Lightning.use("c:DemoLightingOutApp", function () {
            $Lightning.createComponent("c:SendDataToVFPage", {
                strParentId: '{!Account.Id}', // passing parameters to Lightning Component
            },
                "vfDemo",
                function (component) {
                    console.log("Lightning component rendered successfully!!");
                    // Event Service hander to handele the lightning component cusom event
                    $A.eventService.addHandler({ "event": "c:SendDataToVFPage", "handler": retriveEventData });
                });
        });


        function retriveEventData(event) {
            var recordTypeId = event.getParam("currentRecId");
            var eventRecordData = event.getParam("CurrentRecDetails");

            // passing data to outputtext lables
            document.getElementsByClassName("accName")[0].innerHTML = eventRecordData.Name;
            document.getElementsByClassName("accIndustry")[0].innerHTML = eventRecordData.Industry;
            document.getElementsByClassName("accPhone")[0].innerHTML = eventRecordData.Phone;
        }

    </script>
</apex:page>
```

**Step 5** :- Create Detail page button on the account select button type as visualforce and add the button to the Page Layout.
That's it.
Click the button from account record the component will render from vf page.

Reference Link :- [this](https://www.salesforcecodecrack.com/2019/06/send-data-from-lightning-component-to.html#:%7E:text=add%20your%20component%20in%20lightning%20out%20App.&text=Create%20Visualforce%20page%20and%20include,%3AincludeLightning%20%2F%3E%20in%20page.&text=Create%20Detail%20page%20button%20on,That%27s%20it.)

Comment: Thanks @Priya  .I am trying to embed VF page in LC. I tried this approach but this is helpful if we are trying to embed LC in VF page.